# Use the same column in both group by and partition by in BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, partition-by

I have a table TAB with 5 columns,
col1: string ('AAA', 'BBB', ...)
col2: string (null, 'XYZ', ...)
col3: timestamp ('2020-01-01 00:00:00', ...)
col4: string ('A1A', 'B1B', ...)
col5: string ('A2A', null, ...)

Sample Data

```
WITH TAB AS 
(SELECT 'AAA' col1, null col2, TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00' col3, 'A1A' col4, 'A2A' col5    
UNION ALL   
SELECT 'AAA', null, TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00', null, 'A2A'  
UNION ALL   
SELECT 'AAA', 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00', null, 'A2A' 
UNION ALL  
SELECT 'BBB', 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-02 00:00:00', 'B1B', null )
```

My query which didn't give intended result,

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  DATE(col3) as date,
  COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col4),"") IS NULL) AS col4_isnull_total,
  COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col5),"") IS NULL) AS col5_isnull_total,
  COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col2),"") IS NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, DATE(col3) AS col2_isnull_total
FROM TAB
WHERE DATE(col3) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
GROUP BY col1, col2, DATE(col3)
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is,

| col1 | col2 | date | col4_isnull_total | col5_isnull_total | col2_isnull_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | null | 2020-01-01 | 11 | 15 | 3 |
| AAA | XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 30 | 45 | 3 |
| AAA | ABC | 2020-01-01 | 10 | 5 | 3 |
| AAA | null | 2020-01-02 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| AAA | XYZ | 2020-01-02 | 3 | 45 | 1 |
| AAA | ABC | 2020-01-02 | 10 | 5 | 1 |
| BBB | null | 2020-01-01 | 7 | 5 | 4 |
| BBB | XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 3 | 35 | 4 |
| BBB | ABC | 2020-01-01 | 14 | 19 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Intended result from the Sample Data,

| col1 | col2 | date | col4_isnull_total | col5_isnull_total | col2_isnull_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | null | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 | ***2*** |
| AAA | XYZ | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| BBB | XYZ | 2020-01-02 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

So, basically I want aggregate by col1, col2 and DATE(col3)  and find number of nulls using `group by` and also the number of nulls in col2 by col1 and DATE(col3) using `partition by`

The error I get is,
`PARTITION BY expression references column col3 which is neither grouped nor aggregated`

Comment: would you try `GROUP BY 1, 2, 3` instead. ?  or `GROUP BY col1, col2, date` ?

Comment: I tried both, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below query.

```sql
WITH TAB AS (
  SELECT 'AAA' col1, null col2, TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00' col3, 'A1A' col4, 'A2A' col5    UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA', null, TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00', null, 'A2A'    UNION ALL   
  SELECT 'AAA', 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00', null, 'A2A'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BBB', 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-02 00:00:00', 'B1B', null
)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       DATE(col3) AS date,
       COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col4),"") IS NULL) AS col4_isnull_total,
       COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col5),"") IS NULL) AS col5_isnull_total,
       ANY_VALUE(col2_isnull_total) AS col2_isnull_total,
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
           COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col2),"") IS NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, DATE(col3)) AS col2_isnull_total
      FROM TAB
     WHERE DATE(col3) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
  )
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

[image]

Below is a query without using subquery (not recommended. not readable, subject easily to be broken)

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       DATE(col3) AS date,
       COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col4),"") IS NULL) AS col4_isnull_total,
       COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col5),"") IS NULL) AS col5_isnull_total,
       IFNULL(FIRST_VALUE(IF(NULLIF(TRIM(col2),"") IS NULL, COUNTIF(NULLIF(TRIM(col2),"") IS NULL), NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w, 0) AS col2_isnull_total2
  FROM TAB
 WHERE DATE(col3) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY col1, ANY_VALUE(DATE(col3)) ORDER BY col1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
;
```

Comment: I tried the ANY_VALUE(), it didn't work. Please execute your suggestion for the following, the count for col2 should be 2 for col1 'AAA' but instead it's 1.

`WITH TAB AS (
  SELECT 'AAA' col1, null col2, TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00' col3, 'A1A' col4, 'A2A' col5
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA', null, TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00', null, 'A2A'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAA', 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00', null, 'A2A'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BBB', 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-02 00:00:00', 'B1B', null
)`

Comment: Would you update the question with your sample and expected result as well ? I think you want the window function is evaluated before the aggregation function.

Comment: are you able to explain why *col2_isnull_total* of second row is `1` , not `2`  in your output?  It seems little bit different what I've updated.

Comment: Yeah, it should be 2, thanks. Are there no other ways apart from the nested query solution like having both under the same level of the query.

Comment: Since an aggregate function is evaluated before a window function, normally it's not possible.  But in your specific case, there might be a workaround that I don't personally recommended.

Comment: I've added another version which doesn't use a subquery. kindly check that out.